# R package to analyze sales promotion cannibalization?

Tags: r, correlation, cross-correlation, promotions

My dataset consists of weekly sales data of thousands of products, for hundreds of stores. Occasionally, there is a promotion in one week, leading to spikes in the sales of the promoted product. During the promotion week, the sales on other products can drop, i.e. cannibalization.

I am a little familiar with the arules package, which can help identify association rules between products.

Yet, how could we identify the products being cannibalized through the sales promotions? Is there a similar package like arules, just for cannibalization?

Comment: I am interested in this question, did you manage to find an answer or some help on analysing cannibalisation effects in the end?